# Google Spreadsheet: add automatically the same formula in each new row of a column. Also with "SUM"

Tags: google-sheets

I have this sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10YVUO2a-XftaCOX73tOiOwQfu0t80iKPJjQrRDiht1A/edit?usp=sharing

In the column "E" I need the same operation as ARRAYFORMULA in column C and D.

In column E I need to make a simple SUM and this is what does not work.

How do I resolve?

**UPDATED:**

Can I use this magic formula:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A;A1:A*(2*B1:B);""))

but with SUM?

I need to use this magic formula which repeat for every rows the formula i choose, but I need repeat in each rows a formula with SUM that now doesn't work. How to?

Comment: See if this can help you: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53364/what-is-the-best-approach-to-adding-additional-costs-to-items-in-google-spreadsh/53447#53447 - or this: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51558/add-a-creation-date-value-when-a-new-line-is-edited

Comment: While it's great to offer an example spreadsheet to show what you're trying to do, your question really should have enough information to stand alone. When that link no longer works (after you've decided that you no longer need the file) this question will be of no use to anyone else.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal, neither link can solve my problem. I'm wrong? You may try in my sheet linked?

Comment: Come on, can be so difficult?

Comment: Dear peanuts, sorry if I have not explained well. Now I will try to do it properly. 

I need in column "E" to have the same automatic formula I get with the formula that I have written in column "D". 

Only in column "E" I need a SUM function does not work. Clear now? Open the link and see by yourself.

Comment: Please anyone... it's for my school!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question is: how can I provide a product of the sums of columns A and B, from the current row down to the end of the sheet, and apply this automatically down the column with an array formula?

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(ROW(A:A);">="&ROW(A:A);A:A)*SUMIF(ROW(B:B);">="&ROW(B:B);B:B))`

As per OP request, this will populate a header, and mask any output on rows where there is nothing in column A or B:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A:A)*LEN(B:B),IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Counter",SUMIF(ROW(A:A);">="&ROW(A:A);A:A)*SUMIF(ROW(B:B);">="&ROW(B:B);B:B)),))`

Comment: Wow. Fantastic. Great. For all that the "geniuses" told me over here before you I was feeling very stupid. Thanks a lot, real genius.

Comment: Just one more thing: If I want to put a title in the first row of the column?

Comment: For the title: If I add this: =ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1; "Counter"; ArrayFormula(SUMIF(ROW(A:A);">="&ROW(A:A);A:A)*SUMIF(ROW(B:B);">="&ROW(B:B);B:B))) the title works, but the column continue with error to the bottom of the file and is not what I need. The error is: "Error: The arguments of the matrix for IF are of a different size." How to?

Comment: I can't really see an issue with your formula (the second ArrayFormula is unnecessary, but shouldn't affect it). Can you double check this is the exact formula you have used (copy and paste it directly from the sheet, perhaps).

Comment: Et voilà! This is the exact formula from my spreadsheet: =ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1; "Counter"; ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(Games!A:A);">="&ROW(Games!F:F);Games!F:F)/SUMIF(ROW(Games!A:A);">="&ROW(Games!C:C);Games!C:C)*100))). Everything works (also if I add a row from the middle), but after last cell that has content the other cells are full of error: "Error: The arguments of the matrix for IF are of a different size." How to?

Comment: One more thing: if I add more rows in the linked spreadsheet there appear a lot of cells with "0". I don't want them!

Comment: The first ROW() needs to reference the Games sheet. The second requirement may be achieved by wrapping in and IF() function. Will provide the formula when I'm at a desktop.

Comment: Are you at desktop now? :)

Comment: Yes, sorry - have edited the answer (hopefully you can adapt the references to suit).

Comment: I'm using the new Google Spreadsheet. The correct formula is: =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A:A)*LEN(B:B); IF(ROW(A:A)=1; "Counter"; SUMIF(ROW(A:A);">="&ROW(A:A);A:A)*SUMIF(ROW(B:B);">="&ROW(B:B);B:B));)). Thanks a lot, friend.